# Python Vosk speech recognition добавление словаря

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Каким образом можно добавить словарь распознавающих слов в Vosk python. Мне нужно распознавать определенный, конечный набор слов/команд, а не всю речь. Подскажите как это реализовать? Я знаю что есть документация, но я не могу ничего понять от туда. Буду благодарен если опишите весь процесс пошагово.

Comment: https://alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation ?

Comment: @Violet Хотелось бы, чтобы пошагово расписали как это делать, имея txt со словами